# What means are available for recourse if I was ripped off by a business?

Tags: united-states, fraud

I contacted a business, initially via telephone then email, after seeing a product on their webpage and ended up paying for an item ($5,000). Over the course of a month, the item was never shipped and the representative from the business (self-described as "President" and likely the sole employee) has begun ignoring my correspondence and as it stands appears to have no intention of shipping my item. What sort of steps can I take to begin either getting my money back or applying some sort of pressure that might convince the business to respond to me? I've began looking at things such as BBB reviews or Federal Trade Commission complains but it appears that neither of those lead to any action.

Details of the transaction:

- The business is located in a different state than I am (I'm in IL, business is in NC).
- I have a lot of email correspondence back and forth detailing the transaction, mentions of when shipping would take place, an invoice from the business for the purchase, etc.
- I paid via a bank transfer to an account in the name of the business.
- I'm in contact with several other people who have also had similar experiences with said business (keeping people's money, lack of communication, etc).

Comment: Call the county attorney of the county in NC where the business is located and ask them what you can do. They may already know of the business's bad dealings.

Comment: If you paid by credit card yo may be able to cancel the charges. You could also sue them. A prosecutor or law enforcement is likely to call this a civil matter, but the impact to multiple people may tip the balance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can sue them.
2. You can ask your bank to reverse the transaction citing fraud.
3. You can report them to the police.

If the business is legitimate then these will probably work. If the business is a front for a con-artist then write off your money.

Comment: I can't imagine the bank reversing a complete transfer.